# iphone python or perl processor, or similar

Tags: iphone, python, scripting, compiler-construction

I have an application to develop but the problem is that is must download part of behavior as a list of instructions from a server.

Ideally it will download scripting code and execute it. The question is if there are any libraries to make it? For example, I have python script and I want to to execute it on device...

Any options?

thank you

Comment: So, you basically want to run Python on the iphone?

Answer (score 1):

Lua is very popular for games.  You can embed Python, too.  Apple won't enforce the "Objective-C only" clause unless you make it obvious that you use Python to script behavior. Do you think all the games on the store are scripted in Objective-C?  No way.  Just don't make your transgressions obvious and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, the app store does not allow apps containing programming languages capable of executing arbitrary code on the phone, so your app's market would be limited to users willing to jailbreak their phones to circumvent this restriction.

You could, depending on what you want to do, look at using the browser's JavaScript.

Comment: Wait a sec. He would be downloading script code, which is just data. So its not like its downloading compiled objective-C code (which BTW, Im not even sure if you could, you could get the system to execute it if they had the MMU setup to not allow data segments to run code). Does that still hold?

Comment: David, you can mprotect the data segments to be read-write, write to them, and then mprotect again for execute permissions.  The real trouble is subverting dyld, as dyld is very aggressive in its manner.  I think if dyld was more passive then lots of apps would silently be auto-updating.

Comment: Basically, if the code's coming to you from off the phone, they don't like it. If your app ships with the interpreter and the code, that's fine. Section 3.3.2 of the app store agreement.